# Sort "allKeys" with mapping

Tags: json, swift, swift4

I decode a JSON with dynamic string keys which looks like this:

```
{
"dynamickey1":
    {"infos1": "blabla","infos2": 21},
"dynamickey2":
    {"infos1": "blabla","infos2": 12},
... }
```

They are sorted as I wanted, as I put a list of string in the URL. But when it decodes the dictionary with the code below **(EDIT : i put the complete code)**, I lost the order:

```
struct Devise {
    let nom : String
    let EUR: Float
    let ETH: Float
}

struct DataPrix {
    let devises: [Devise]
    struct DataPrixCodingKeys: CodingKey {
        let stringValue : String
        init?(stringValue: String) {
            self.stringValue = stringValue
        }
        var intValue : Int? {return nil}
        init?(intValue: Int) {return nil}
    }

    enum DeviseCodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case ETH
        case EUR
    }
}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()

extension DataPrix: Decodable {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy : DataPrixCodingKeys.self)
        self.devises = try (container.allKeys).map { key in
            let devisesContainer = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: DeviseCodingKeys.self, forKey: key)
            let deviseName = key.stringValue
            let EUR  = try devisesContainer.decode(Float.self, forKey: .EUR)
            let ETH  = try devisesContainer.decode(Float.self, forKey: .ETH)
            return Devise(nom: deviseName, EUR: EUR, ETH: ETH)
        }
    }
}
```

So is it possible to sort them alphabetically at this point or at least keep the same order I had in my initial list?

Comment: As always, don't use `NSDictionary` in Swift.

Comment: How does it "not work"?

Comment: @Sweeper sorry i edited, i have the error ````Ambiguous reference to member '<'````

Comment: Try using `(<)` to refer to the operator as a function rather than an application of it inline.

Comment: @ItaiFerber same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more likely a problem with the type of `container`. It seems you are using `NSDictionary`, which has `allKeys` of type `Any`. `Any` is not `Comparable`.

The simplest solution is to *cast* the dictionary to `[String: Any]`. Then you can use directly `container.keys.sorted()`, where `<` is the default comparator.

```
let jsonString = """
{
  "dynamickey1": {"infos1": "blabla","infos2": 21},
  "dynamickey2": {"infos1": "blabla","infos2": 12}
}
"""

let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)!
if let container = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: [])) as? [String: Any] {
    let sortedKeys = container.keys.sorted()
    print(sortedKeys)
}
```

Or, switch to using `Codable` protocol and decode the JSON type-safely:

```
let jsonString = """
{
  "dynamickey1": {"infos1": "blabla","infos2": 21},
  "dynamickey2": {"infos1": "blabla","infos2": 12}
}
"""

let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)!

struct Info: Codable {
    let infos1: String
    let infos2: Int
}

let parsed = try? JSONDecoder().decode([String: Info].self, from: jsonData)

if let container = parsed {
    print(container.keys.sorted())
}
```

**EDIT** Solution for the updated question:

```
let jsonString = """
{"XPR": {"EUR":0.6866,"ETH":0.001088}}
"""

let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)!

enum Currency: String, CodingKey, Comparable {
    case XPR
    case EUR
    case ETH

    public static func < (lhs: Currency, rhs: Currency) -> Bool {
        return lhs.rawValue < rhs.rawValue
    }
}

struct Devise: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let rates: [Currency: Double]

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        name = decoder.codingPath.last?.stringValue ?? ""
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: Currency.self)

        var rates: [Currency: Double] = [:]
        try container.allKeys.forEach {
            rates[$0] = try container.decode(Double.self, forKey: $0)
        }
        self.rates = rates
    }
}

struct DataPrix: Decodable {
    let devises: [Devise]

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: Currency.self)
        devises = try container.allKeys.sorted().map {
            return try container.decode(Devise.self, forKey: $0)
        }
    }
}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
do {
  let exchangeRates = try decoder.decode(DataPrix.self, from: jsonData)
  print(exchangeRates)
} catch {
  print(error)
}
```

However, if your keys are truly *dynamic*, you cannot avoid a dictionary and the best would be just to use it:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
do {
  let exchangeRates = try decoder.decode([String: [String: Double]].self, from: jsonData)
  print(exchangeRates)
} catch {
  print(error)
}
```

Comment: Does it take in account the dynamic keys ? I have an error when i want to cast the dictionary, i edited my original post with the complete code !

Comment: @TmSmth I really wonder why you are even using such a system with "dynamic keys". Could you please post the JSON you are trying to parse? Why are you not parsing `[String: String]` directly?

Comment: because if i understood correctly, the name of your variable / case in the struct and enum have to be the same than the json dictionnary. However, i request price for assets so the dynamic keys is the name of the asset so i can't create a variable / case with only one name. So URL can be this https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=XRP&tsyms=EUR,ETH or this https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=XLM&tsyms=EUR,ETH

Comment: @TmSmth The whole point of your dynamic keys is to simulate a dictionary without having a dictionary... and you end up having a `NSDictionary`. Why don't you just parse into `[String: [String: Double]]`?

Comment: @TmSmth I have updated my answer with a simpler solution for your problem. It could be much simpler to just parse automatically into `[String: [String: Double]]` but I have used an `enum` for the keys to make the data model nicer.

Comment: i tried your code but if, in the json data, the name is not XPR it doesn't work. And i don't want to hardcode every name possibilty so i need something dynamic

Comment: @TmSmth Than just use `[String: [String: Double]]` as I keep saying.

Comment: So why did they bother to do all of this in the course i read if you have only to parse this kind of array ? You mean i have to replace ````let dataPrix = try! decoder.decode(DataPrix.self, from: data)````by ````let dataPrix = try! decoder.decode([String: [String: Double]].self, from: data)```` and remove the enum and the struct ?

Comment: @TmSmth Yes, if you have truly dynamic keys, you cannot avoid a dictionary. If you don't want to hardcode currencies as an enum, there is no need for anything else.

Comment: Well that works thanks, i amazed that it was so simple, what's the point to do all those struct and enum stuff then ?

Comment: @TmSmth Well, that's when you want to make sure the keys have only some specific values. For example, if you have a name mapping for every supported currency or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort like this:

```
let dictionary  = ["key1":"test","key0":"","key5":""]
dictionary.keys.sorted { $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending }.map { key in
    // code
}
```

so for your Code you can use Like this

```
  let keys = dic.keys.sorted { $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending }
    print( keys.map { (key) -> [String : Devise]? in
        guard let value = dic[key] else {return nil}
        return [key : value]
        }.compactMap({$0}))
```

Comment: I can't cast the dictionary as ````[String:Any]```` I edited my original post with the complete code

Comment: @TmSmth check   updated code i have codable code if you want